# Python to mailmerge csv to word in continuous in one document

Tags: python, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I want to mailmerge a table in **csv(List.csv) to word(example1.docx) but continuously into multiple pages in one word document**. The function is something like "Next Record" in MS Word. I have a template (Test.docx). I can't find in Python.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
from mailmerge import MailMerge
from datetime import date

# Define the templates - assumes they are in the same directory as the code
template_1 = "Test.docx"
df1 = pd.read_csv('List.csv')
looprange = range(int(len(df1.index)))

for j in looprange:
    document_1 = MailMerge(template_1)
    document_1.merge(
        BusinessName=df1.BusinessName[j],
        Name= df1.Name[j],
       )
document_1.write('example1.docx')
```

**List.csv**

[image]

**Test.docx**

[image]

However, I only get the output of the last input and is only one page and it is repeated data. Desired output suppose to be suppose to be **all 4 row data** in two pages. T**he data should be different left and right as I split the template to two column.**

**Output currently:**

[image]